# List of JSON records into Pandas Panel?

Tags: python, json, pandas, panel

I have a list of json records to read into pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'eurusd': {'buy': 1, 'sell': 2}, 'eurcny': {'buy': 3, 'sell': 4}},
        {'eurusd': {'buy': 5, 'sell': 6}, 'eurcny': {'buy': 7, 'sell': 8}}]

>>> pd.DataFrame(data[0])
         eurcny  eurusd
 buy        3       1
 sell       4       2
```

I wonder if it is possible to do something like:

> pd.Panel(data, items=['buy', 'sell'], major_axis=[0, 1], minor_axis=['eurusd', 'eurcny'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panel accepts a dict of DataFrames, so you could just pass that:

```
In [11]: pd.Panel(dict(enumerate([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in data])))
Out[11]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: buy to sell
Minor_axis axis: eurcny to eurusd

In [12]: pd.Panel(dict(enumerate([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in data])), items=['buy', 'sell'], major_axis=[0, 1], minor_axis=['eurusd', 'eurcny'])
Out[12]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: buy to sell
Major_axis axis: 0 to 1
Minor_axis axis: eurusd to eurcny
```